# How to add space in between font-awesome icons in a horizontal row

Tags: html, css, padding

Been going at this for quite some time now.  I think my brain just hurts from coding for too long heres my html:

```
<div class="icons">
    <a href="www.twitter.com/bigmakes15"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="www.facebook.com/makie.michaux"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="www.instagram.com/bigmakes15"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
</div>
```

and heres my css:

```
.icons a {
    display: inline;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 363px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fa, .fa-instagram, .fa-twitter, .fa-facebook {
     padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: How do you want it to look like?

Comment: i think a simple &nbsp; 's  could solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Your html is not right try this fix:

```
    <a href="www.twitter.com/bigmakes15"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="www.facebook.com/makie.michaux"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="www.instagram.com/bigmakes15"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
```

and try this css:

```
display: block;
margin-right: 15px;
```

or

```
 display: block;
padding-right: 15px;
```

Comment: thats the same thing, i think your talking about how theres a space in between the instagram tag and thats just a typo in stack

Comment: no you forgot to close you a tag just copy and paste the code i gave you and replace it

Comment: you had <a href="www.instagram.com/bigmakes15"<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>

it was supposted to be  <a href="www.instagram.com/bigmakes15"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>

Comment: ok! i see..i fixed it. but it still didnt do what i want. i would like something around this https://gyazo.com/dc811e61b6c842d2e614427cf6f3ca2c

Comment: and make sure you have display:block

Comment: did you add display: block yet?

Comment: i really appreciate everything tho

Comment: did you leave the html the way i had it and just add the css to the .fa, .fa-instagram, .fa-twitter, .fa-facebook  selector?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the trouble correctly, it's a combination of the html problem @jack smith caught and then either conflicting styles from somewhere else or the `position: fixed` - not sure what that's doing there, but in the code you've provided that's going to make them all lump together.

Note also that in your CSS you can just say `.fa {...}` instead of `.fa, .fa-instagram, .fa-twitter, .fa-facebook {...}` since those all have the `fa` class. In this snippet I'm using `.icons i` but it could just as well be `.icons .fa` or, if you want this to apply to all font awesome icons, just a bare `.fa`

```css
.icons a {
  margin-right: 10px;/*space to the right of the blue*/ outline
  padding-right: 10px;/*between the red and blue outlines*/
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  
  /* you can add any of these */
  /*
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  top: 363px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
  */
}
.icons i {
  padding-right: 10px;/*space before the red outline*/
  margin-right: 10px;/*also between the red and blue*/
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="icons">
    <a href="www.twitter.com/bigmakes15"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="www.facebook.com/makie.michaux"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="www.instagram.com/bigmakes15"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
</div>
```